# Error: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found

Tags: android-studio, selenium-webdriver, appium, applitools

I am trying to automate an android hybrid app using Appium and Selenium but keep getting following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It
>   is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which
>   takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not
>   accessible
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>       System info: host: 'MAVRLT567', ip: '192.168.2.56', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_162'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:93)
>         at com.applitools.quickstarts.Appium_native_java.main(Appium_native_java.java:41)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:185)
>         ... 13 more
>       Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
>   error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'UiAutomator' and
>   platformName 'Android'. Please check your desired capabilities.
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 230 milliseconds
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>       System info: host: 'MAVRLT567', ip: '192.168.2.56', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_162'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
>         ... 18 more

Comment: Can you please try to add dependency for "commons-io-2.6.jar" and then clean and build project again. Let me know once you have done it.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Check/Post your appium server log just before above error